# Determining where a repeated enum falls on a larger scale

Tags: delphi, math, enums

I have an enumerated type, for example

```
type
  TMyEnum = (meOne, meTwo, meThree);
```

Now I need to make a function which determines which enum falls on a larger scale, assuming the enum values repeat infinitively...

```
function EnumOf(const Value: Integer): TMyEnum;
begin

end;
```

Think of it like weekdays where the set of enums continuously repeats. If I pass in the number `5` (for example number of days) it should return `meTwo`, because...

```
1) meOne
2) meTwo
3) meThree
4) meOne
5) meTwo <--
6) meThree
```

And the number `7` would return `meOne`, and so on.

How should I write this function?

Comment: Use mod on the Value and hope that your enum has contiguous values so you can determine the number of elements by `High(TMyEnum) - Low(TMyEnum) + 1`

Comment: What would you expect 0 to be returned as?

Comment: There will be no zero, it starts from 1

Comment: Your problem actually consists of two parts (which, ideally, you should have realised before you posted it): First, the mathematics: how to obtain the remainder in an integer division? Second, the Delphi-specific part: how to convert between enum constants and integers? I answered the mathematical part, and David answered both in a single answer. (Didn't downvote, though.)

Comment: The function header should be declared as `function EnumOf( const Value: MyRange): TMyEnum`. And `MyRange` is `type MyRange = 1..maxInt;`. This ensures type safety of input values to the function.

Comment: @LURD does that really help? Doesn't it make it awkward to use such a function. What if the input variable is stored in an integer. How do you then call the function?

Comment: @David It doesn't really matter, it's a helpful precaution which should be common in any shared programming libraries.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, no problem calling the function with an integer variable, MyRange is handled as a subset of an Integer by the compiler. Inproper input is caught with Assert(Value>0) at runtime, and `en := EnumOf(0)` at compile time.

Comment: @LURD Then what does the subrange actually do for you?

Comment: @David, it's there to alert the programmer about the intended use of the function. It's a language construct seldom used but nevertheless practical in cases like this. And as I said, EnumOf(0) is caught at compile time. CodeInsight will give guidance to the programmer as well.

Comment: @LURD I think I'd just use the Assert. Nobody is going to call the function with a literal. You'd simply use the matching enumerated type literal. To me the range brings complexity (extra type) for no real gain. I'd Assert and document.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the mod operator:

```
function EnumOf(const Value: Integer): TMyEnum; 
begin
  Assert(Value>0);
  Result := TMyEnum((Value-1) mod (1+ord(high(Result))));
end;
```

The Value-1 adapts the 1-based indexing of Value to the 0-based indexing of enumerated types.

Comment: @kobik Then you can accidentally change the return type and forget to change to body and so break the function. So I personally prefer to say *high of the return value, whatever type it happens to be*

Comment: Yeah, but you did use `TMyEnum((Value-1)` in the same line. If you weren't using that already I would have agreed with you.

Comment: @kobik Fair enough. It's habit of mine to use high(Result). In this case there's no way to avoid repeating the type. In which case you might be right that self-consistency is better.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `mod` operator:

```
132 mod 5 = 2
```

because

```
132 = 26*5 + 2
```